# Where is the libpcap library for QNX Neutrino?

Tags: c, linker, libpcap, qnx, momentics

I know QNX 6.6 has libpcap as part of its standard libraries.

When I link to libpcap.a and try to use the functions, I get "undefined reference to 'function_name'".

Where is the real libpcap library I need to get it to actually work? Is there someplace I need to download it from?

---

I am building from Momentics, so there is no single command to build.

Under Linker > other options I have -lpcap, and under Linker > extra libraries I have pcap.

A possibility is that I need to import additional libraries, but libpcap comes with hundreds and I have no idea which ones I would need.

As for output, I get some innoculous building messages followed by my project search path, followed by 18 of these about different functions:

```
U:/.../target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(fad-getad.o): In function pcap_findalldevs':
(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `getifaddrs'
```

Some of which are in pcap.h and some aren't. This is the complete list:

> 'U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(scanner.o): In function `pcap_lex':
>   (.text+0x9c8): undefined reference to`getaddrinfo'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(inet.o): In function `pcap_lookupnet':
>   (.text+0x6d8): undefined reference to`socket'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(inet.o): In function `pcap_lookupnet':
>   (.text+0x744): undefined reference to`ioctl_socket'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(inet.o): In function `pcap_lookupnet':
>   (.text+0x7c8): undefined reference to`ioctl_socket'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(pcap-bpf.o): In function `pcap_set_datalink_bpf':
>   (.text+0x16): undefined reference to`ioctl_socket'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(pcap-bpf.o): In function `pcap_stats_bpf':
>   (.text+0x21a): undefined reference to`ioctl_socket'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(pcap-bpf.o): In function `pcap_setdirection_bpf':
>   (.text+0x3ef): undefined reference to`ioctl_socket'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(pcap-bpf.o):(.text+0x49d): more undefined references to `ioctl_socket' follow
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(fad-getad.o): In function`pcap_findalldevs':
>   (.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `getifaddrs'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(fad-getad.o): In function`pcap_findalldevs':
>   (.text+0x175): undefined reference to `freeifaddrs'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(gencode.o): In function`gen_mcode6':
>   (.text+0x5777): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(gencode.o): In function`gen_scode':
>   (.text+0x5b36): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(nametoaddr.o): In function`pcap_nametoaddr':
>   (.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `gethostbyname'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(nametoaddr.o): In function`pcap_nametoaddrinfo':
>   (.text+0x93): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(nametoaddr.o): In function`pcap_nametonetaddr':
>   (.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `getnetbyname'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(nametoaddr.o): In function`pcap_nametoport':
>   (.text+0xee): undefined reference to `getservbyname'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(nametoaddr.o): In function`pcap_nametoport':
>   (.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `getservbyname'
>   U:/shutchinson/QNX/target/qnx6/x86/usr/lib\libpcap.a(nametoaddr.o): In function`pcap_nametoproto':
>   (.text+0x251): undefined reference to `getprotobyname'

Comment: Maybe you're doing something wrong when linking. Show the command you're running and its output.

Comment: It gives you an undefined reference to getifaddrs, which is not a pcap function. Perhaps you also need to link to the socket library.

Comment: What's the full list of functions for which you're getting an "undefined reference"?  (It *did* find `pcap_findalldevs()`, but `pcap_findalldevs()` calls `getifaddrs()`, and it *didn't* find `getifaddrs()`.)

Comment: Eddited to add the complete list.

Comment: @GreySag  So did you try to link to the socket library ? That would be the `-lsocket` flag (after any flags for linking to the pcap library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add another library (libsocket.a) to the linker options. I.e. your linker options must be.............. -lpcap -lsocket.